# How to calculate lambda for a contraction of the Fredholm Operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

We have the Fredholm equation,

$$\phi(x)=\psi(x)+\lambda\int_0^\pi \cos (x+y)\phi(y)dy$$

where the Fredholm operator is the integral operator in the given equation. The value of $\lambda$, can be varied according to give a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(operator_theory)) or [dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(operator_theory)) of the operator.

Suppose the Kernel $K(x,y)=\cos(x+y)$ and $\phi(x)$ are continuous on the square
$$(a<x<b,a<y<b)$$ such that:

$$|K(x,y)|\leq M$$

Then we have a contraction if $$|\lambda|\leq\frac{1}{M(b-a)}$$

The Kernel is $\cos(x+y)$ and the interval to be on the square $0<x<\pi,0<y<\pi $, so then I would like to calculate $\lambda$ to give a contraction. I selected $x=y=\pi/2$ since $\pi/2$ is in the square. So I got $|\cos(\pi)|=1$. So I thought this would be $\lambda$. However, this is not right.

Then I tried to calculate $\lambda$ as such

$$\frac{1}{M(b-a)}\rightarrow \frac{1}{\cos(\pi-0+\pi-0)}=\frac{1}{\cos(2\pi)}=1$$

But is this correct interpretation of the theorem of contraction? If not, how does one calculate the correct value for $\lambda$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K(x,y)= \cos (x+y)$ an $a=0, b = \pi$, then $M=1$, thus

$$| \lambda| \le \frac{1}{\pi}.$$

Comment: Thanks. I see that M=1, as I got,  but where did $\pi$ come from in your answer?

Comment: We have $|\lambda|\leq\frac{1}{M(b-a)}$ with $M=1, a=0, b= \pi.$

Comment: I see now, I though (b-a) were a variables of M. Thanks for this clarification.